# Why does $x^{\log_a y} = y^{\log_a x}$ ? (intuitive reason)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logarithms, intuition

So I have seen mathematical proofs for this. They used other logarithmic identities to get this result. I am looking for a more intuitive approach to this and not just equations which lead to this.

edit: okay so what I mean by intuitive is that,
x^{power of a which gives y} = y^{power of a which gives x}.
So is there a way to make sense of it using pure logic and not identities?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The **definition** of a logarithm is a kind of "logarithmic identity." You can't understand the equation at all, intuitively or not, without using some such "identities." How did you see this fact proved, and why wasn't the proof intuitive to you? (Please add this information to the question using the "edit" button, using the formatting advice from the previous comment.)

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a proof I like. Whether it's "intuitive" depends who's asking.
$$
x^{\log_a y} = (a^{\log_a x})^{\log_a y} = (a^{\log_a y})^{\log_a x} = y^{\log_a x}.
$$

Comment: "In mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them." - John von Neumann

Comment: It might be worth looking at examples, like $a=10$, $x=100$, and $y=1000$. In this case the equation says$$100^{\log_{10}(1000)}=1000^{\log_{10}(100)},$$or$$100^3=1000^2.$$

Comment: Well $anything = a^{\log_a anything}$.  So $x=a^{\log_a x}$ and $y=a^{\log_a y}$.  And as $(b^c)^d = b^{cd}= b^{dc}=(b^d)^c$ we have $x^{\log_a y} = (a^{\log_a x})^{\log_a y}=(a^{\log_ay})^{\log_a x} =y^{\log_a x}$.

Answer (score 9):

$$ (a^m)^n=(a^n)^m,$$

where $a^m$ is $x$ and $a^n$ is $y$.

Comment: woah okay I got it now thanks

Answer (score 1):

By definition

$$Y=\log_a y \iff a^Y =y \iff y^\frac 1 Y=a$$
$$X=\log_a x \iff a^X =x\iff x^\frac 1 X=a$$

therefore

$$x^\frac 1 X=y^\frac 1 Y \iff x^Y=y^X$$

or in other words

> $$x^{\log_a y} = y^{\log_a x} \iff x^{\frac1{\log_a x}} = y^{\frac1{\log_a y}} \iff a=a$$